# What software applications are used for translating a book?

Tags: software, translation

I'm translating a book. I would like to do it with a software that allows me to see the original one in a window and my translation in the other with an auto-scroll down. Can I do it with LibreOffice? What prominent software applications are used by the publishing industry?

Comment: There are several [diff tools](https://www.google.de/search?q=diff+tools&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=8dOkUuOuCMeEtAbW-4C4BQ) out there showing two files next to each other and scroll down both files simultaneously. They are made for comparison, but can be used for your purpose also. If you also need spell checking they may not be the best option.

Comment: I use vimdiff to edit similar files, but have never done translation, so I don't know if someone has made a special mode for it. (probably did, they make them for everything else.)

Answer (score 2):

I've found [Translation Table](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/translation-table) for LibreOffice this is not an advanced tool but for little works is useful:

> Translation Table creates a two column table, where in the first
>   column you get the source text segmented by sentence, each sentence in
>   a cell, and in the second column you can put your translated
>   sentences, each one in opposite cells to the source sentences. It is
>   not a CAT (Computer Aided Translation) tool, for such, please take a
>   look to Anaphraseus extension or OmegaT project.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia lists a selection of [computer-assisted translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation) tools.

You might also try to search your favourite search engine for "translation workstation" or "translator's workstation".