# Book translation from English to Portuguese

Tags: tools, translation

I have a 200 page manuscript which I need to translate from English to Portuguese.  I am looking for the best software application authors use for this purpose.

Comment: Related question: [What software applications are used for translating a book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/9661/26)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What software applications are used for translating a book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/what-software-applications-are-used-for-translating-a-book)

Answer (score 6):

Translation is best done by humans. There is no software available to push a button and Make This Portuguese, and even if there is, word-for-word translation simply can't capture the nuance and meaning of idioms and language-specific phrasing. Saying someone "has horns" in European countries means something very specific which doesn't exist in English, for example.

Translation services are a big deal. There are entire companies which do just this, and you should vet and review even their work and not assume it's right.

Comment: Shoot, even within the English language, I have a hard time some times understanding my friends in Scotland and New Zealand.  Some things just cannot translate because it's not a part of our slang as you said.

Comment: I understand it perfectly but my thinking here is that I really need to obtain a piece of software that would "coarsely" translate my book and then pass it on to a Portuguese speaking expert that would "totally edit" it instead of having it totaly translated by a human before Editing and designing.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: if that's all you want, you can throw it into Babelfish https://www.babelfish.com/ or Systran https://store.systran.us/lp/storeSystran?Langue=en_US, but since your translator would have to have the original ms to compare against anyway, you aren't saving any labor or brainpower.

Comment: A machine-translated version would be worse than useless as a starting point for an actual translation. It's very hard to edit sense into something that makes no sense; it's much easier to just start with the original and translate it all correctly.